# Calculating power emitted from electronics

Tags: power, noise, signal, thermal

I am trying to figure out how much "thermal noise" electronics may produce as I am trying to detect the cosmic microwave background radiation, but the electronics surrounding the detector will obviously pick up noise from the equipment.

I wanted to know if there was a way to calculate how much to expect.

I am attempting to use a signal to noise ratio of \$\frac {power of signal} {power noise}\$ to see if I get near the golden 1:1 ratio.

The issue is I don't know how to estimate the approximate power of the noise from electronics.

Comment: *but the electronics surrounding the detector will obviously pick up noise from the equipment* - surely, if designed correctly, you are interested in what false noise the detector detects because that is the sensitive part of your circuit.

Comment: As it's thermal noise, you can estimate the source transmission with a thermometer. Seriously! Then you can reduce it for emissivity, a shiny mirror-like surface radiates little. Similarly for attenuators and feedlines. Zero loss is like having a shiny surface. When you have loss, say you have a 1dB pad, or 1dB of loss in a feedline, that loss creates noise as per its temperature. Therefore any lossy parts of your detector need to be cooled. I'm sure there's plenty of tutorial stuff out there to be found with your favourite search engine, about what Penzias and Wilson did with their receiver

Answer (score 2):

You can measure the cosmic background radiation using relatively simple equipment.

[The guys in this report did it,](http://portia.astrophysik.uni-kiel.de/~koeppen/CMB.pdf) and I've read reports from others who did it as well.

I have a [setup that could be used for those measurements.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/3-rfcamera-toc) I haven't gotten the software finished to actually do it, though.

The usual way to account for thermal noise is to calibrate it out.

You take measurements with the dish pointed at objects with a known temperature, and measure the intensity of microwaves that they put out.  From that, you can figure the measured intensity for any temperature.  If you extend the line down to absolute zero, then you'll find a microwave intensity that is non-zero.  That's the thermal noise contribution of the whole system.  Ideally, there would be no radiation at absolute zero so any value above zero is the error (thermal noise) of your equipment.

The linked report describes using liquid nitrogen and ambient temperature as two calibration points.

It also describes using ambient temperature and heated water as calibration points.

Both experiments delivered results that agree with the commonly accepted value for the CMB.

If you search on the names (Piat alone or Stein and Förster together) then you can probably locate their own reports of their work.

---

The difficulty with trying to do anything with a signal to noise ratio here is that the signal you are trying to pick up is noise.  It is simply wide band noise, and a typical receiver will pick up a portion of it because the receiver has a limited bandwidth.

Whatever you do, you'll have to calibrate your equipment to read as a temperature.  You just do the calibration so that you can pick out the total system noise as well.

---

Stein and Förster were high school kids in Germany when they made their measurements of the CMB.

Answer (score 0):

read up on the concept of Noise Temperature.

Useful examples come from NASA, on the effective noise temperatures for their 70 meter
dish antennas in Goldstone CA, Madrid and Canberra.

They work thru all the math on their frontends, cooled to about 20 degrees Kelvin (-253 Centigrade).

I just searched for "nasa deep space network noise temperature" and here is the first link

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19830005061